# Use GitHub like dropbox using source tree

Tags: github, resources, atlassian-sourcetree

I know this question is something odd but I have to ask this as required,

Can I set automated process using source tree that have the functionality that my local repository will automatically sync with GitHub repository?

Or can we use any other thing instead of the source tree to automate this?
(Like Dropbox sync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automating commits may sound like a good idea, but I strongly advise against it. Commits are most useful when they're made deliberately.

In general:

- A commit should record one change, not many
- A commit should record a consistent change, e.g.

  - If you're working in C you probably don't want changes to your header file to be committed without  corresponding changes to your C file
  - If you're working with an MVC framework you probably don't want to commit a change to your model without generating migrations or updating your views
- A commit should have a helpful commit message

Automated commit systems can't guarantee any of these things. I advise you to get comfortable with manually committing your work. It will pay off.